# Swift4 imagepicker giving me "Class 'viewcontroller' has no initializers"

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

I just started to learn swift and have almost no background on developing.

I'm making an app which involves image picker.
While making such function, I get this message saying Class 'viewcontroller' has no initializers. 
How do I initialize viewcontroller? 
I've searched other posts, but due to my lack of knowledge on developing languages, I'm having hard time understanding the solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class viewcontroller: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet var imgView: UIImageView!

let imagepicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
var captureimage: UIImage
var videoURL: URL!
var flagImageSave = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnCaptureImageFromCamera(_sender:UIButton) {
    if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)) {
        flagImageSave = true

        imagepicker.delegate = self
        imagepicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagepicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
        imagepicker.allowsEditing = false

        present (imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

@IBAction func btnLoadImageFromLibrary(_sender: UIButton) {
    flagImageSave = false
    imagepicker.delegate = self
    imagepicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagepicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]
    imagepicker.allowsEditing = true

    present (imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString

        if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as NSString as String) {
            captureimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

            if flagImageSave {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(captureimage, self, nil, nil)
            }

            imgView.image = captureimage

        }
    }


 }







func btnCaptureImageFromCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
 func btnLoadImageFromLibrary(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Comment: you need to read up an study swift, this question cannot be answered, u are at the risk of "close" on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, style should be `ViewController` (not `viewcontroller`), and ideally more descriptive like `TheImageViewController` but anyway...

At a guess the issue is:

```
var captureimage: UIImage
```

Try:

```
var captureimage: UIImage?
```

As you have a non-primitive type, that is not ? or ! (read swift docs)

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it has helped so future people can see.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you declared `captureimage` property as non optional but haven't provided any instances of this property. To fix this you can either provide default value

```
var captureimage: UIImage = UIImage()
```

or make `captureimage` property optional

```
 var captureimage: UIImage?
```

Comment: videoURL is _OK_ because it is implicitly unwrapped, maybe not the safest option, however perfectly valid and technically 'initialised'